# select all -x vertices (to delete for mirror modifier)

Tags: vertices, selection-tools, mirror

Title pretty much says it all. I want to select all vertices with -x coordinates so i can delete them to replace them with the mirror modifier. mesh is a high density sculpt so using the box select isn't an effective option.

Comment: *"using the box select isn't an effective option"* it can be if object is oriented in global space so that it's possible to enter orthographic mode and select everything from one side with it. Other than that it really depends on mesh. If it has good edge flow you could hide center edge loop and use Select Linked to select one half. Or use Symmetrize in Sculpt mode

Comment: What about, select all in Edit mode, then header menu > Mesh > Symmetrize tool?

Comment: @MrZak its a large sculpt with some high density details to the point where i have to zoom really close up and clean up a bunch of verts that were close enough to the center that they were missed

Comment: @moonboots I do use symmetrize a lot while sculpting to make sure there is a centerline and true symmetry but there are many things that tool cant do that i need done with the mirror modifier like multiple symmetries, custom symmetry axis, and moving forward i generally always end up having to delete one whole side for the mirror mod because of the way the mirror mod allows rigs to have mirrored weight painting and what not.

Comment: @moonboots on a related note do you know if there is a way to flip the direction symmetrize mirrors? like instead of left to right, right to left.

Comment: Yes in the operator box (bottom left of the 3d view) you can choose -x to x or x to -x etc...